# how do i round a number to three decimal points. in c++

Tags: c++

i want a way to round a number like this to three decimal points

17.3205

to

17.321

18.9737

to

18.974

and if the output is integer 120
it will be like this 
120.000
but i want to understand how not only a function write it,

help :) !

Comment: Do you actually need it rounded, or just printed in this format?

Comment: i want it to be rounded and in this format :D

Comment: like in this picture 
http://postimg.org/image/gw15todvp/